# Nginx giving error 403 only on location /

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I am trying to serve static html files via nginx. In my nginx config, I have:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/django/django_project/static/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    location /static/admin {
        alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin;
    }
    location /static  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static;
    }
    location /minion {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # this is what im talking about
    location /html {
         alias /home/django/django_project/static/html;
    }
    location / {
         alias /home/django/django_project/static/html;
    }
}
```

(note how the two last definitions are identical aside from the location path). Now, if I go to mywebsite.tld, I get a 403 error for some weird reason, while going to mywebsite.tld/html works exactly as it is supposed to be.

What is the explanation for this behaviour? What mistake did I make so it does this? Obviously, the file perms are ok, the index and files all exist (since /html works), it has to do with the `location /`, but I dont have a clue why it would... Please help me out here.

Comment: Read carefully alias directive doc

Comment: And I see no reason to have last two `location` block at all.